# How do I find a subset of samples in a 2D matrix given a non-axis-aligned rectangle?

Tags: algorithm, math, unity-game-engine, geometry

I'm writing a small video game prototype and I have a heightmap (2D float array) that will be traversed by objects. I want to be able get the heightmap data under the objects for use in the game.

[image]

I currently get a sub-region (yellow) of the heightmap under my objects with an AABB (Axis-aligned bounding box), as I'll be working with data both under and around them. That part is trivial.

However I can't figure out how to find the samples (red) under the objects given a rotated bounding box (not axis aligned). How might I do this?

Comment: This problem looks similar to a rasterization problem.  I suggest looking up resources for scanline rasterization.  I'm aware that the problem may be described in terms of triangles rather than rectangles, but in this case it's rather trivial to convert a non-axis-aligned rectangle into two triangles and rasterize each separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might suggest the following scheme:

1. Calculate AABB of your wheel (by its vertices).
2. Get the rectangular subgrid of points within this AABB.
3. For each of these points check whether it lies within your wheel.

In order to do part 3 you'll need to do some math. Suppose that you know unit direction vector `D` of your wheel, position of its center `C`, half-length `l` and half-thickness `w`. For a point `P`, you can check the following conditions:

```
  abs(  dot(P - C, D)) <= l
  abs(cross(P - C, D)) <= w
```

Here is a bit more complex way to solve the problem, but more efficient. Enumerate only rows of the subgrid obtained with AABB check. For each row you can determine range of points in it within the wheel by using explicit formulas in *O(1)* time. Then you can enumerate only the points within your wheel. Total time complexity is *O(R + A)*, where *R* is the nubmer of rows in subgrid within AABB of the wheel, and *A* is the total number of points within the wheel.

Example implementation in C#:

```
if (Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Dot  (hfSampleGlobalPos - wheelPosePos, wheelPoseRot * Vector3.forward))   <= wheelRadius &&
    Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Cross(hfSampleGlobalPos - wheelPosePos, wheelPoseRot * Vector3.forward).y) <= wheelHalfWidth)
{
    // Do something with the sample under the wheel here
}
```

Comment: Are you able to be more specific of the direction vector? I have a Quaternion rotation, and can get from that the direction vector of any direction or the euler angle.

Comment: Additionally, the cross product of 2 Vectors is another Vector - What element of the resultant Vector should we be checking if <= w?

Comment: @S.Richmond You need direction vector `D`, which has unit norm, and is aligned with the box of your wheel. There are four possible directions. The sign does not matter, since your wheel is symmetric. There are still two options. You can choose any of them, but `l` must be length in direction of your chosen `D` vector. If you change `D` to orthogonal vector, then you have to swap `w` and `l`. Cross product in 2D space is a single value (Z-coordinate of 3D vector).

Comment: @S.Richmond If you operate in XZ plane, then you should check Y coordinate of cross vector.

Answer (score 0):

Filling in polygons on a raster is a standard problem in computational geometry. You can look up the words "[even-odd rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even%E2%80%93odd_rule)" to get you started. However, here's a rough outline of what you do:

1. Loop thru each scan line in you yellow sub-region
2. Intersect the scan line with each blue polygon edge
3. Sort the intersection points by x value
4. Fill interior pixels between intersection points using the even-odd rule to determine interior points
5. Finally, you have to guard against degenerate cases like intersecting with vertices and horizontal lines.

Also, for simple polygons the eve-odd rule reduces to a [point-in-polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) problem.